# Charge Conjugation Operator in Supermultiplet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, supersymmetry

Consider an $\mathcal{N}=1$ left-handed chiral supermultiplet. The particle content is

$$L = (\phi\quad e_L) $$

where $\phi$ is a complex scalar and $e_L$ a left handed Weyl fermion.

People usually denote a right-handed fermion as $\bar{e}$ or $e^c$ (see for example [this review](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356)). 
So we can say that $e_R$ is the same as $\bar{e}$ or $e^c$.

If I have $\bar{e}_R$ field, i.e $e_R^\dagger \gamma_0$, is that just the same as $e_L$?